# Proving a set is a basis for a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

The set $\{u_{1},u_{2}\cdots,u_{6}\}$
is a basis for a subspace $\mathcal{M}$ of $\mathbb{F}^{m}$ if and
only if $\{u_{1}+u_{2},u_{2}+u_{3}\cdots,u_{6}+u_{1}\}$
is also a basis for $\mathcal{M}$.
So far I have that the two basis are just rearranged sums of each other but don't know where else to go with it.

Comment: Well, there are two criteria for a set to be a basis. Have you tried proving either of them?

Comment: To prove a set is a basis, you need to show that 1) the elements are *linearly independent*, and that 2) the set spans the subspace in question.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$A=\{u_{1},u_{2}\cdots,u_{6}\}$
and
$B = \{u_{1}+u_{2},u_{2}+u_{3}\cdots,u_{6}+u_{1}\}
$.

If $B$
is a basis for a subset $M$,
then each element of $M$
is a linear combination
of elements of $B$.
Since each element of $B$
is a linear combination of
elements of $A$,
each element of $M$
is a linear combination
of elements of $A$,
so $A$ is a basis of $M$.

To go the other way around,
we only have to show that
each element of $A$
is a linear combination
of elements of $B$.
That is,
we want to solve
$\{v_1=u_{1}+u_{2},v_2=u_{2}+u_{3},\cdots,v_6=u_{6}+u_{1}\}$
for the $u_i$
in terms of the $v_i$.
But this is a 
standard exercise 
in linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach:

The set $\{u_{1},u_{2},\dots,u_{6}\}$ is a basis (of some subspace) $\iff$
The set $\{u_{1},u_{2},\dots,u_{6}\}$ is linearly independent $\iff$
The matrix $M$ whose columns are $u_1,\dots,u_6$ has the kernel (nullspace) $\{0\} \iff $
The matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1&&&&&1\\1&1\\&1&1\\&&1&1\\&&&1&1\\&&&&1&1} \cdot M 
$$
has the kernel $\{0\}$